# LayoutInflater and ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am still fairly new to android, but I am getting there!

I have created an ExpandableListView almost identical to the api sample code on the android developers [website](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html). The ExpandableList works wonderfully.

I tried creating custom layouts through xml and a SimpleExpandableAdaptor and had nightmares. Which brings me to the point:

I have been reading a lot about LayoutInflaters and how well they work with XML files. However, I would like to create two seperate ImageButtons and place them next to the groupExpanded indicator (in the group TextView) with out referencing xml. I don't think I can use xml to do this simply because the code supplied by API doesn't rely on xml, its created runtime.

Can LayoutInflater work in this situation (no xml)? Does anyone have suggestions where I might look for a clean solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe LayoutInflater is used for the express purpose of loading an XML layout into a View object. Alternately, you can create your own view by constructing RelativeLayout/LinearLayout etc. and programmatically adding your ImageButtons to it

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
layout.addView(imageButton1);
layout.addView(imageButton2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do both, either inflate a xml layout using a LayoutInflater or creating the View elements using the Android object model. I would suggest using xml files as you can easily change the layout to a later point without touching the code.

Have a look at [this blog](http://qtcstation.com/2011/03/working-with-the-expandablelistview-part-1/) post it shows how to inflate layouts in an adapter for a ExpandableListView.

Comment: Both of these routes worked. I would give you a little check mark.. but there it won't let me give two!! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Deal... just as soon as I hit 15 rep!